# Вывод на экран массива массивов

Tags: c#, .net

Всем привет , не понимаю как выводить на консоль элементы двухмерного массива которые лежат в одномерном массиве, подскажи пожалуйста как это сделать

```
  int[][,] array2d = new int[3][,]
 {
  new int [,] { { 3,1}, {4,2} },
  new int [,] { { 7,3},{8,11} },
  new int [,] { {17,12} ,{21,73} }
 };`
```

Comment: вроде понял вот что  у меня получилось                                                                                                             
              for (int i = 0; i < array2d.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < array2d[0].GetLength(0); j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < array2d[0].GetLength(1); k++)
                    {
                        Console.Write (array2d[i][j, k] + " ");
                    }
                   
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

Comment: но если добавляю еще элементов в двумерные массивы то дополнительные не отображаются

Comment: у вас 3 цикла. в конце тела 2-х внешних циклов должно быть `Console.WriteLine();`. `array2d[0].GetLength(0)` заменить на `array2d[i].GetLength(0)`, тоже самое, очевидно, и для `.GetLength(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Я хотел сделать это в одну строку... Но не смог ;(

```
string.Join(",", a.Select(z => z.Cast<List<int[]>>().Select(x => x.Select(c => c))).ToList());
```

Поэтому вот развёрнутый рабочий вариант:

```
int[][,] a = new int[3][,]
{
    new int [,] { {3,1}, {4,2} },
    new int [,] { {7,3},{8,11} },
    new int [,] { {17,12} ,{21,73} },
};
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Array:");
for (int q = 0; q < a.Length; q += 1)
{
    sb.Append("\n");
    for (int w = 0; w < a[q].GetLength(0); w += 1)
    {
        for (int e = 0; e < a[q].GetLength(1); e += 1)
            sb.Append(a[q][w,e] + " ");
        sb.Append("\n");
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Array:
3 1 
4 2 

7 3 
8 11 

17 12 
21 73
```

Вы так же можете поиграть с вариациями, как пример, получить на выводе:

```
int[][,] a = new int[3][,]
{
   new int [,] { {3, 1}, {4, 2} },
   new int [,] { {7, 3}, {8, 11} },
   new int [,] { {17, 12}, {21, 73} },
}
```

С помощью:

```
int[][,] a = new int[3][,]
{
    new int [,] { {3,1}, {4,2} },
    new int [,] { {7,3},{8,11} },
    new int [,] { {17,12} ,{21,73} }
};
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder($"int[][,] a = new int[{a.Length}][,]\n" + "{");
for (int q = 0; q < a.Length; q += 1)
{
    sb.Append("\n   new int [,] { ");
    for (int w = 0; w < a[q].GetLength(0); w += 1)
    {
        sb.Append("{");
        for (int e = 0; e < a[q].GetLength(1); e += 1)
        {
            sb.Append(a[q][w, e]);
            if (e + 1 != a[q].GetLength(1))
                sb.Append(", ");
        }
        sb.Append("}");
        if (w + 1 != a[q].GetLength(0))
            sb.Append(",");
        sb.Append(" ");
    }
    sb.Append("},");
}
sb.Append("\n}");
Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

Comment: Ужасный код, знаете почему? А вот почему `sb.Append(a[q][w,e] + " ");`. Любому человеку, даже автору, имея такие наименования и в таком кол-ве, придется листать код, смотря что за `q`, `w` и `e` такие, ведь они совершенно не отражают суть того, что содержат в себе, простой рандом по клавиатуре. Не экономьте на буквах, возьмите за правило называть все своими именами. Вот что такое `a`? Наверно входные данные, так почему не назвать просто `data`? Что такое `q`? Судя по коду, индекс данных, то есть можно назвать `dataIndex`, ну и т.д. И уже, по названию переменной становится ясно что делает код.

Comment: Касательно "однострочного варианта", у вас тоже есть ряд неточностей, к примеру почему `.Cast<List<int[]>`? Там же многомерный массив чисел, при касте вы можете получить все значения разом, но не коллекцию, с массивом внутри. Ну и если делается строка, то надо все уровни обработать через `string.Join()`, приведя к строке. То есть, должно получиться нечто такое: `var result = string.Join("\n\n", data.Select(jagged => string.Join('\n', jagged.Cast<int>().Chunk(jagged.GetUpperBound(1) + 1).Select(arr => string.Join(',', arr)))));`.

Comment: q,w,e несёт в себе индекс, это сразу понятно. Для лямбда-выражений всегда использую z,x,c без каких-либо проблем

Comment: Индекс чего? Ок, я даю вам такой код `k[q] = 15`, поясните мне, что он делает не в плане C# логики, а в плане некого проекта? Думаю нет, ибо чтоб понять, что такое `k`, вам надо листать вверх, искать эту переменную в коде и смотреть от куда она получилась, а если там будет еще и чет по типу `k = new d(f);`, то пока не поймете все эти классы, значения, вы не поймете за что этот код отвечает. Собственно, вот и вся проблема. А если будет допустим `UsersBalance[person.Name] = 15`, то уже даже такая строка, начинает обретать смысл, который позволяет без листания кода понять, что тут происходит.